# group by slows down the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have on the products table the following index: **(product_t,productid,forsale)**. The MySQL manual says:

*The GROUP BY names only columns that form a leftmost prefix of the index and no other columns.*
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html

When I do the following query

```
SELECT z.product_t, COUNT(z.productid)
FROM xcart_products z
JOIN xcart_products_lng w ON z.productid = w.productid
AND w.code =  'US'
WHERE z.forsale =  'Y'
group by z.product_t
```

And therefore using the left most index field (product_t), the execution time is still massive:

```
+-----------+--------------------+
| product_t | COUNT(z.productid) |
+-----------+--------------------+
| B         |                  4 |
| C         |              10521 |
| D         |                  1 |
| F         |                 16 |
| G         |                363 |
| J         |                 16 |
| L         |                749 |
| M         |                 22 |
| O         |                279 |
| P         |               5304 |
| S         |                 22 |
| W         |                662 |
+-----------+--------------------+
12 rows in set (0.81 sec)
```

When I use the whole index (product_t,productid,forsale), the execution time is blazing fast (0.005 seconds). How should I change it to make the query go faster?

[image]

**I think the query somehow could be improved through the use of a semi join... However i'm not sure how...**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan pls check my new answer. I managed to do it haha

Comment: GOOD NOTHING IS IMPOSSIBLE!! .. Very Well ..I will read your answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slow down might not be related to the GROUP BY clause. Try adding an index for w.code and  z.forsale individually.

[MySQL Profiling](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/mysql-servers-built-in-profiling-support/) might also help you in your endeavour

Comment: adding the indexes for w.code and z.forsale unfortunately didn't improve anything. I checked the profiling and i saw an anomoly. The major bottleneck is Sending data 0.124638

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious answer would be to create a new index for product_t only. Cany you create new indexes?

Comment: however i reckon you can per query only use one per table... I've added the execution plan and two indexes. The one i mentioned (product_t,productid,forsale) and a second one of only product_t. You can see it only takes the first one. If it wouldn't, the forsale and productid fields would slow up the query...

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully I found a way how to increase the speed. I did have another table where all the product_t's are defined. Each product_t there also uses the 'code' field (to specify the translation of each product_t). In this table I have an index defined on product_t and code as well. By changing the query to:

```
SELECT z.product_t, COUNT(z.productid)
FROM xcart_products z
JOIN xcart_products_lng w ON z.productid = w.productid
JOIN xcart_products_product_t_lng p ON z.product_t = p.product_t
AND p.code =  'US'
WHERE z.forsale =  'Y'
group by p.product_t,p.code
```

I managed to increase the speed to 0.10 seconds. The reason why it's faster is because the grouping by is now done on a whole index. Secondly the where code='US' is replaced from the big products_lng table, to the small product_t_lng table. I think this is the most efficient the query can be...

```
mysql> SELECT z.product_t, COUNT( z.productid )
        -> FROM xcart_products z
        -> JOIN xcart_products_lng w ON z.productid = w.productid
        -> JOIN xcart_products_product_t_lng p ON z.product_t = p.product_t
        -> AND p.code =  'US'
        -> WHERE z.forsale =  'Y'
        -> GROUP BY p.product_t, p.code
        -> ;
    +-----------+----------------------+
    | product_t | COUNT( z.productid ) |
    +-----------+----------------------+
    | B         |                    4 |
    | C         |                10521 |
    | F         |                   16 |
    | G         |                  363 |
    | L         |                  749 |
    | M         |                   22 |
    | O         |                  279 |
    | P         |                 5304 |
    | S         |                   22 |
    | W         |                  662 |
    +-----------+----------------------+
    10 rows in set (0.14 sec)
```

Comment: Good, For how much data you checked it out?...My Suggestion check it with large size.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks! 22,343 products. The database is just using the normal settings and hasn't been tuned.